# String processing of XML into PHP displaying table of data in browser?

Tags: php, html, xml, string

I'm doing some study for college using explode in PHP and wanted to try to process some XML as a string to display a table of the data in the browser. I want to display a HTML table, with appropriate table headings, where each attribute is its own column, and there is a new row for each student.

The last row in the table should span all columns, and include the text ‘Number of students: 12‘ (where the number is calculated). I was thinking of using `explode` on the string but so far I can only display the data - can someone push me in the right direction please?

```
<html>
    <head><title>Week3</title></head>

<body>
       <?php 

    $xml = '<students> 
            <student> 
            <student_number>12121212</student_number> 
            <f_name>Alan</f_name> 
            <s_name>Hannaway</s_name> 
            <module>SWD</module> 
            <lecturetime>1:00</lecturetime> 
            <lab_time>2:30</lab_time> 
            <group>A</group> 
    </student> 

    <student> 
            <student_number>13131313</student_number> 
            <f_name>Peter</f_name> 
             <s_name>Jones</s_name> 
             <module>PDS</module> 
             <lecturetime>12:00</lecturetime> 
             <lab_time>1:30</lab_time> 
             <group>B</group> 
    </student> 

    <student> 
             <student_number>14141414</student_number> 
             <f_name>Clare</f_name> 
             <s_name>Murphy</s_name> 
             <module>SWD</module> 
             <lecturetime>1:00</lecturetime> 
             <lab_time>2:30</lab_time> 
             <group>B</group> 
    </student> 
    <student> 
            <student_number></student_number> 
            <f_name>Jack</f_name> 
            <s_name>Cobane</s_name> 
            <module>PDS</module> 
            <lecturetime></lecturetime> 
            <lab_time></lab_time> 
            <group></group> 
    </student> 

    <student> 
             <student_number>18181818</student_number> 
             <f_name>Rachel</f_name> 
             <s_name>Hartings</s_name> 
             <module>SWD</module> 
             <lecturetime>1:00</lecturetime> 
             <lab_time>2:30</lab_time> 
             <group></group> 
    </student> 

    <student> 
             <student_number></student_number> 
             <f_name>John</f_name> 
             <s_name>Molloy</s_name> 
             <module></module> 
             <lecturetime></lecturetime> 
             <lab_time>11:30</lab_time> 
             <group>A</group> 
    </student> 

    <student> 
             <student_number>20202020</student_number> 
             <f_name>David</f_name> 
             <s_name>Hutchinson</s_name> 
             <module>SWD</module> 
             <lecturetime>1:00</lecturetime> 
             <lab_time>2:30</lab_time> 
             <group>A</group> 
    </student> 
</students>';

$students = explode("<student>", $xml);
    echo '<students>';
    foreach($students as $student){
        echo '<tr>';
        if($students != "<students>"){
            $studentNamesOnly = explode("</student>" , $student);
            echo '<br>';
        }                   
        foreach($studentNamesOnly as $studentName){
            echo '<td>';
            echo $studentName;
            echo '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</students>'; 

          ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the output I have so far:

```
12121212 Alan Hannaway SWD 1:00 2:30 A 

13131313 Peter Jones PDS 12:00 1:30 B 

14141414 Clare Murphy SWD 1:00 2:30 B 

18181818 Rachel Hartings SWD 1:00 2:30 

20202020 David Hutchinson SWD 1:00 2:30 A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. it is work perfect

```
    $xml = '<students> 
        <student> 
        <student_number>12121212</student_number> 
        <f_name>Alan</f_name> 
        <s_name>Hannaway</s_name> 
        <module>SWD</module> 
        <lecturetime>1:00</lecturetime> 
        <lab_time>2:30</lab_time> 
        <group>A</group> 
    </student> 

    <student> 
        <student_number>13131313</student_number> 
        <f_name>Peter</f_name> 
         <s_name>Jones</s_name> 
         <module>PDS</module> 
         <lecturetime>12:00</lecturetime> 
         <lab_time>1:30</lab_time> 
         <group>B</group> 
    </student> 

    <student> 
         <student_number>14141414</student_number> 
         <f_name>Clare</f_name> 
         <s_name>Murphy</s_name> 
         <module>SWD</module> 
         <lecturetime>1:00</lecturetime> 
         <lab_time>2:30</lab_time> 
         <group>B</group> 
    </student> 
    <student> 
        <student_number></student_number> 
        <f_name>Jack</f_name> 
        <s_name>Cobane</s_name> 
        <module>PDS</module> 
        <lecturetime></lecturetime> 
        <lab_time></lab_time> 
        <group></group> 
   </student> 

    <student> 
         <student_number>18181818</student_number> 
         <f_name>Rachel</f_name> 
         <s_name>Hartings</s_name> 
         <module>SWD</module> 
         <lecturetime>1:00</lecturetime> 
         <lab_time>2:30</lab_time> 
         <group></group> 
</student> 

<student> 
         <student_number></student_number> 
         <f_name>John</f_name> 
         <s_name>Molloy</s_name> 
         <module></module> 
         <lecturetime></lecturetime> 
         <lab_time>11:30</lab_time> 
         <group>A</group> 
</student> 

<student> 
         <student_number>20202020</student_number> 
         <f_name>David</f_name> 
         <s_name>Hutchinson</s_name> 
         <module>SWD</module> 
         <lecturetime>1:00</lecturetime> 
         <lab_time>2:30</lab_time> 
         <group>A</group> 
</student> 
       </students>';

$students = explode("<student>", $xml);
$stArr = array();


foreach ($students as $student) {

        preg_match_all("/<.*?>(.*?)<\/.*?>/", $student, $matches);
        $stArr[] = $matches[1];
}


echo "<table border=\"1\" >";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>student_number</th>
      <th>f_name</th>
      <th>s_name</th>
      <th>module</th>
      <th>lecturetime</th>
      <th>lab_time</th>
      <th>group</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($stArr as $arr) {

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
     echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
}

echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: it has to use explode();

Comment: you don't need to use explode. with ajax you get a file data of xml file. this is like `file_get_contents` with php. if you like my answer please mark  up and rate it . thanks

Comment: i dont understand ajax and we have never done it in college we are using explode at the moment thats why i want to use it here

Comment: i understand that but there is no point me doing it if i dont know what it does how it works. I have studied it and dont plan to till my lecturer says so. He wants us to use explode.

Comment: you know jquery? if you know , you understand it very fast

Comment: no i dont :/ can you try rewrite that using explode function

Comment: see my edit in answer and mark up and rate  if it is that you want . thanks

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but it is necessary here - regular expressions are categorically the wrong way to process XML. Given the OP's new question, I suspect he has been sent on a wild goose chase. It is much better to advise people to use a proper XML processor, like DOMDocument or SimpleXML.